# How to re sharp (join) arabic letters in c++

Tags: visual-c++

well i need help in solving this issue, i want to join the arabic letters in a way to look like this " السلام عليكم " not like this " ا ل س ل ا م  ع ل ي ك م "

here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){SetConsoleOutputCP(1256);
SetConsoleCP(1256);


string name;
string line;
unsigned int curline=0;
cin >> name;

ifstream thefile;
    thefile.open("text.txt");
    while (getline(thefile, line)){
        curline++;
        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos && name.size() == 
line.size())
            cout << "found" << name<<curline;
    }
thefile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

now in this code i'm getting the words from a file.